# Печать графика по времени используя Oxy Plot Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, oxyplot

Пишу программу для построения графика на Windows Form. Использую Nuget OxyPlot 1.0.0. Делаю как в примерах из документации:

```
public void PrintChart()
    {
        var model = new PlotModel { Title = "DateTimeAxis" };

        var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
        var endDate = DateTime.Now;

        var minValue = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(startDate);
        var maxValue = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(endDate);

        model.Axes.Add(new DateTimeAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Minimum = minValue, Maximum = maxValue, StringFormat = "M/d/h" });
        frGraph.Model = model;
    }
```

Но дата по оси Х какая-то не валидная...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, что бы время дата отображалась в 24 часовом формате времени например: "hh:mm"

Comment: У вас уже есть решение данной задачи (вроде) в коде. А именно `StringFormat=` укажите нужный формат того, как будет выглядеть ваша полоса. Подробнее читаем [тут](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/axes/DateTimeAxis.html)

Comment: Спасибо, что-то проглядел. С датой все в порядке, а время выводит постоянно только 12:00:00 (StringFormat = "hh:mm:ss")

Comment: Все работает, просто масштабирование нужно немного настроить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не забывайте оформлять как ответ

Comment: @Ev_Hyper А это разве ответ?) У автора как он написал дальше -
 проблема в масштабе была. А что за масштаб - я уже не представляю, да и как то не задавался этим вопросом...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ возможно и не ответ, если код в достаточной степени описывает проблему, то уточнить этот момент не сложно.